# nginx rewrite rule haven't result

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I try to use nginx's rewrite for changing urls like

```
    <domain>/index.php?mode=a/b
```

to

```
    <domain>/a/b
```

but my attemps haven't result.

```
    location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ index.php?mode=$1 break;
    }
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues:

- All `nginx` URIs have a leading `/` (unlike Apache)
- The `.php` file will be processed in a different location (presumably `location ~ \.php$`, and therefore the `break` should be replaced with `last`

Try this:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?mode=$1 last;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.